# Upper and lower bounds of an alternating sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If an alternating sequence is oscillating away from the x-axis (diverges), e.g. $n(-1)^n$, we know that it isn't bounded. But say we have an alternating sequence that oscillates towards the x-axis (converges to zero), e.g. $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$, is it correct to say that the highest value and lowest value are the upper and lower bounds, respectively; because from what I can remember from calculus II, bounds didn't matter when it came to alternating series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether bounds "matter" depends on what you want them for. Without knowing what you want these for, I can't say.

In general an *upper bound* on a function $f$ (a sequence is just a function whose domain is the natural numbers) is *any* value $M$ such that $f(t) \le M$ for every $t$ in the domain. A *lower bound* is *any* value $m$ such that $m \le f(t)$ for every $t$ in the domain. Thus functions do not have unique upper or lower bounds. Any number higher than an upper bound is also an upper bound. Any number lower than a lower bound is also a lower bound. So talking about "the" upper or lower bound is inaccurate. You may refer to the "least upper bound", or the "greatest lower bound", which are unique, if they exist. But in this case, you probably just want any upper bound and any lower bound.

If a sequence coverges, whether it is alternating or not, then it is guaranteed to be bounded both above and below. By the definition of convergence, there is some $N$ such that if $n > N$, then $|a_n - L| < 1$, where $L$ is the limit. So $$ L-1 < a_n < L+1$$
For $n > N$, the sequence is bounded by $L - 1$ below and $L + 1$ above. For $n \le N$, there are only a finite number of values, so there is a maximum and a minimum value. The larger of the maximum value and $L + 1$ is an upper bound for the entire sequence, and similarly, the lesser of the minimum value and $L - 1$ is a lower bound for the entire sequence.

If the sequence doesn't converge, then it may have bounds, or may not.